# Why doesn't the bit-shift of a variable and a number have the same result?

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I'm shifting some bits and just realized that doing the operation using a variable doesn't have the same result as using a number. See the example below.

```
int a = 97;
int b = 0;

b = 1 << a;
printf("%d\n", b); 
// 2

b = 1 << 97;
printf("%d\n", b); 
// 0 - warning: shift count >= width of type [-Wshift-count-overflow]
```

Comment: In the first case I your compiler did not try to detect the overflow. In the second case since it was a number it's easy to detect

Comment: How many bits are in your integer?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews 32 bits.

Comment: You realize that there are less than 97 bits in your integer?  Shifting more than 31 positions is a waste of execution time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the result of a [left shift](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic) with a right operand larger than the length in bits of the left operand is undefined, any result is possible from the expression.

In the variable case (`1 << a`), since `a` is 97 (larger than the number of bits in an `int`), the most likely results are `1 << (97 % 32)` == `1 << 1` == `2` or `0`, typically depending on how the hardware (CPU) handles these shifts.

With a constant (`1 << 97`), the compiler knows you're shifting too far, issues the warning (which is not required), and defines the result as `0` (also not required).

Answer (score 4):

The warning you are seeing is a compile time warning. Now, you can clearly see that your `int b` is a 32-bit variable which will be overflown if left-shifted 97 times. So, it's a valid concern. But the compiler can only detect this overflow for the constant number of shifts as it is evaluated during compilation and the compiler immediately knows that it'll overflow.

In case of variable number of shifts, the compiler isn't smart enough to know what value `int a` will posses when it'll come down to shifting. So, the compiler leaves it upto you.

Answer (score 0):

The undefined behavior is outlined in the C++ standard here.

http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.shift

> The behavior is undefined if the right operand is negative, or greater
>   than or equal to the width of the promoted left operand.

You'll get different results depending on compiler and optimization level. If you turn on optimization, the compiler will easily optimize out the first shifting operation and then make it 0 as well.

Why exactly does it act like that though? The x86 instruction for shifting by a variable is SAL (shift-arithmetic-left). You can see the instruction list for bit shifting operations here:

https://c9x.me/x86/html/file_module_x86_id_285.html

The one that would be used in an unoptimized build would be `SAL r/m32, CL`. The `CL` register is 8 bits, but the processor masks it to 5 bits internally:

> The destination operand can be a register or a memory location. The count operand can be an immediate value or register CL. The count is masked to 5 bits, which limits the count range to 0 to 31. A special opcode encoding is provided for a count of 1.